# mule smtp mail unsuccessful issue. ideas

Tags: mule

I'm trying same `host`, `port`, `mailid` from java program , it send mail successfully.

below is my mule smtp flow

```
<smtp:connector name="smtpConnector" doc:name="SMTP"/>

<flow name="sendmail" >
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="8089" doc:name="HTTP" path="sendMail"/>
<smtp:outbound-endpoint  host="15.456.128.61" port="587" user="test"
password="test123" to="xxxxx@xxx.com" from="xxxxx@xxx.com" subject="test mule"
responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="smtpConnector" doc:name="Smtp"/>
<logger message="send mail suceesfully........ " level="INFO" doc:name="mailsend"/>
</flow>
```

http://localhost:8089/sendMail

using mule smtp i got below execption

> Root Exception stack trace: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Comment: when you got the failure  exception message, it would have showed you. How the path , smtp  url goes in to it. Please check on it.

Answer (score 0):

i tested smtp connector and it is working fine in mule flow , below is my code.

but here i used **SMTPS**

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<flow name="yahooemailFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-payload value="#['Test Message ']" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp_host_ip}"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" from="fromemail@yahoo.com"
        mimeType="text/html" password="password" subject="subject"
        to="toemail@yahoo.com" user="fromemail%40yahoo.com" />
    <logger message="Mail Sent #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```